# Is it true that the Chinese manufacturers pay 75% of the cost of the Trump's tariffs?

Tags: tariffs

Is it true that the Chinese manufacturers pay 75% of the cost of the Trump's tariffs?

https://www.econpol.eu/sites/default/files/2018-11/EconPol_Policy_Brief_11_Zoller_Felbermayr_Tariffs.pdf

> The  US  government has strategically levied  import  duties on goods
>   with high import elasticities, which transfers a great share of the
>   tariff burden on to Chinese exporters. **Chinese firms pay
>   approximately 75% of the tariff burden and the tariffs decrease Chinese
>   exports of affected goods to the  United States by around 37%.** This
>   implies that the bilateral trade deficit between the US and China drops
>   by 17%. The additional tariffs generate revenues of around USD 22.5
>   billion, which could subsequently be redistributed in the US.

What cost are we talking about exactly? Because as far as I know, they're not paying them at all since it's the consumer who bear the brunt of the cost if they're buying the Chinese-made items. If they're not buying them, the Chinese manufacturers aren't paying any of the cost since they can put the goods in their inventory and sell it elsewhere, and reducing manufacturing output isn't a cost in any shape of form.

Comment: Did you read the document that you have linked? If yes, which part of Figure 1 was unclear?